# Use multiple cnf files for openssl in Linux

Tags: openssl

I have my original openssl.conf file present in /usr/lib/ssl.
[image: openssl conf pat]

I want to programmatically add some configuration and set that as openssl_conf.

Something like this

```
openssl_conf = default_conf (# add this at the start)
. 
. # original contents of openssl.cnf
.
[default_conf] (# this would be at the end)
.
.
.
```

Now, I don't want to edit the existing configuration file, but add a drop in file instead.
So, something like openssl2.cnf which contains the extra config that I want. And I would want the drop in file to be considered as well.

Would this be possible from openssl conf perspective?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the .include flag -> https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/config.html.

This is how I did it.

I added `openssl_conf = default_conf` at the start of the openssl.cnf file

At the end of the file, I added this `.include /usr/lib/ssl/openssl2.cnf`

My openssl2.cnf contains the extra config. (Something like given below)

```
[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect
...
```